# ColdFusion StructIsEmpty returns NO on empty string

Tags: coldfusion

I'm passing a structure to a function for req. fields validation but I first check whether or not my structure is empty.

If all elements in my structure is empty (emptry string), I don't pass this structure to for validation.

I used `StructIsEmpty` to check my structure. The problem is, when my Structure's elements contain only empty string, `StructIsEmpty` return `NO`. Unfortunately I'm still on **CF8**.

How can I have `StructIsEmpty` to return `YES` when all of the structure elements only has empty string?

```
    <cfset st_MyStruct=StructNew()>
    <cfset st_MyStruct["InstType"]="#Trim(arr[112])#">
    <cfset st_MyStruct["InstId"]="#Trim(arr[113])#">
    <cfset st_MyStruct["PLN"]="#Trim(arr[115])#">
    <cfset st_MyStruct["PFN"]="#Trim(arr[116])#">
    <cfset st_MyStruct["Referal"]="#Trim(arr[118])#">

    cfif StructIsEmpty(st_MyStruct) NEQ "NO">
      <CFINVOKE component="cfcomponents.ValidateFields" method="CheckReqFields"
                                                        st_MyStruct="#st_MyStruct#"
                                                        Inst="#arguments.Inst#" >    

    </cfif>
```

Comment: Empty strings are content.  If you want to use StructIsEmpty, you have to delete the keys that contain empty strings.

Comment: The `"##"` is unnecessary to set a variables `<cfset st_MyStruct["InstType"] = Trim(arr[112])>` works just fine

Comment: also instead of CFINVOKE you should use createObject!

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan said, this struct is not empty. If you want to check if your struct has values that are blank you can do something like this. And check if your `structFieldsAreEmpty` variables true, if it does then your structure has all blank values. If your struct returns more than one entry you would need to modify this code

```
<cfset st_MyStruct = {}>
<cfset st_MyStruct["InstType"] = ''>
<cfset st_MyStruct["InstId"] = ''>
<cfset st_MyStruct["PLN"] = ''>
<cfset st_MyStruct["PFN"] = ''>
<cfset st_MyStruct["Referal"] = ''>

<cfset structFieldsAreEmpty = checkStructValuesEmpty(st_MyStruct) />

<cffunction name="checkStructValuesEmpty" access="private" returntype="boolean" output="false">
    <cfargument name="myStruct" type="struct" required="true">
    <cfloop collection="#arguments.myStruct#" index="i">
        <cfif len(trim(arguments.myStruct[i]))>
            <cfreturn false>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Why loop over the list of keys in the structure when you can loop over the structure itself using `<cfloop collection="#arguments.myStruct#" item="i" >`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a single line, you could serialize the struct to JSON and search that using regex for any non-empty string values, like so:

```
structIsEmptyStrings = refind(':("[^"]+"|\d+|true|false)', serializeJSON(st_MyStruct)) == 0;
```

That regex is looking for any values that are either not empty strings (`""`), numeric, or a boolean value (`true` or `false`). Keep in mind that this will not be accurate if any values in the struct are any types other than string, numeric, or boolean (nested arrays or structs will not be checked). Also, if any string values are only spaces, this will consider the struct to be not empty (which might not be what you're looking for).